# Netsuite : Adding Custom Column on Item Sublist using Suite Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there anyone who can guide/teach me on how to add custom column in the Item Sublist. I'll be using a custom array.
Below is the code that I've been using, but this field displays only on the Item Subtab not on the columns.

var test_column = form.addField('custpage_itg_test_column', 'select', 'Test Column','items','items');

Hoping you can help me guys.
Thanks! :D

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Sir Federico,


I tried to use this one but still returns an error.

var itemsublist = nlapiGetSubList('item');
var test_column = itemsublist.addField('custpage_itg_test_column', 'select', 'Test Column');

Comment: What was your error?